# Injeção de Dependência ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, injeção-de-dependência, asp.net-core, class-library

Estou com uma situação que não sei como resolvê-la. Tenho o seguinte cenário:
Tenho uma ASP.NET CORE WebAPI e uma Class Library também em .NET CORE. Sendo que a class library será de acordo com o Repository Pattern.

Então me deparei com uma dúvida. Realizei a DI da interface/implementação na web api mas dentro da class library não consigo recuperar a connectionString que adicionei no appsettings.json (dentro da class library), acaba retornando null.

Como posso recuperar a connectionString de dentro da class library?

**Edit1:**
O projeto está separado assim

- ProjTeste.API (ASP.NET CORE)
- ProjTeste.Repository (.NET CORE ClassLibrary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vou mostrar como uso no meu projeto que é feito também através do `Repository Pattern` e funciona perfeitamente.

### Startup.cs

Dentro da classe `Startup.cs` crie uma propriedade do tipo `IConfigurationRoot`, caso não exista:

```
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
```

Feito isso, vamos ao construtor da classe `Startup.cs`. Aqui seu arquivo deve-se parecer com o código abaixo.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
        builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
    }

    Configuration = builder.Build();

    Environment = env;
}
```

Perceba o `.AddJsonFile` passando o arquivo `"appsettings.json"` que é onde normalmente se coloca a `connection string`. Creio que o seu projeto esteja também dessa forma.

Perceba também a adição dessa linha `Configuration = builder.Build();`.

Agora vamos ao método `ConfigureServices` também na classe `Startup.cs`. Dentro do método, logo abaixo de `services.AddMvc()`, coloque o seguinte código:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

Feito isso, configuramos com sucesso a DI para o `IConfigurationRoot`.

#### Seurepositorio.cs

Dentro da classe que deseja acessar a `connection string`, crie uma variável do tipo `string` para guardar a sua `connection string`:

```
private readonly string _connectionString;
```

Feito isso, crie o construtor da sua classe da seguinte maneira, informando o `IConfiguration` como parâmetro (o mesmo será criado através da Injeção de Dependência):

```
public SuaClasseRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
}
```

Perceba que usei o `configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");` para buscar a `connection string` do arquivo `appsettings.json` (definimos na classe Startup.cs) e que possui o nome `DefaultConnection`.

Abaixo segue como está meu arquivo `appsettings.json` e ele deve seguir com os mesmos nomes de objetos para evitar problemas futuros:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "myDatabaseConnectionString"
  }
```

Pronto. Agora tem acesso a sua `connection string` em todas as classes que criar da forma que mostrei acima.

Comment: Então, injetando a dependência na API, consigo enxergar a connection string que está no `appsettings.json` da API na `Class Library`? Aliás, o ASP.NET Core 2.0 não já configura por padrão o arquivo `appsettings.json`?

Comment: Sim para ambas as perguntas. Mas o arquivo appsettings.json você pode modificar se desejar, adicionar mais de uma connection string, etc. Coloquei o exemplo do meu para vc ver como ele se parece e se está com a sua connection string lá dentro.

Comment: Agora vi a estrutura do seu projeto. Não era necessário criar outro projeto só pras Libraries. Já que fez assim, coloque um arquivo appsettings.json na sua Class Library tb e tente fazer o que informei acima. Nunca testei dessa forma para saber se funciona.

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Como você disse, queria separar um pouco as coisas, mesmo não tendo necessidade. Mas por fim, injetando na classe`Startup` consigo acessar na Library, certinho como você disse.

Comment: Perfeito! Bom saber que em projetos separados também funciona. Eu uso o Repository Pattern, mas tudo dentro do mesmo projeto! Abraço!

Comment: Vejo o pessoal comentar sobre separar, mas infelizmente dá um pouco de trabalho ou não, dependo do seu conhecimento! Abraço e agradeço pela ajuda novamente!